# Pyspark DataFrame, how to do a Group by aggregation function like Standard Deviation

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Pyspark & Pandas Data Frame, how to do a Group by aggregation function like Standard Deviation

```
data = [['_1','S1',12, 112, 14],
        ['_2','S1',120, 112, 114],
        ['_3','S2',88, 92, 74],
        ['_4','S2',17, 118, 133],
        ['_5','S2',19, 19, 14],
        ['_6','S2',11, 12, 14]]
columns = ['RowNum','School','Subject_1', 'Subject_2', 'Subject_3']
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
dataframe.show()
pandasDF = dataframe.toPandas()

+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
|RowNum|School|Subject_1|Subject_2|Subject_3|
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
|    _1|    S1|       12|      112|       14|
|    _2|    S1|      120|      112|      114|
|    _3|    S2|       88|       92|       74|
|    _4|    S2|       17|      118|      133|
|    _5|    S2|       19|       19|       14|
|    _6|    S2|       11|       12|       14|
+------+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Given Data, Group By School, Find Standard Deviation of Subjects ? Using PySpark
Like Pandas we have

```
def std(x): 
    return np.std(x)


df.drop(['RowNum'],axis=0).groupby('School').agg(['mean', 'max', std])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
column_list = ['Subject_1', 'Subject_2', 'Subject_3']
df = (
    df
    .groupBy('School')
    .agg(
        *[
            *[f.stddev(f.col(element)).alias(f'stddev_{element}') for element in column_list],
            *[f.max(f.col(element)).alias(f'mean_{element}') for element in column_list],
            *[f.max(f.col(element)).alias(f'max_{element}') for element in column_list]
        ]
    )
)
```